# node.js & rabbitmq - publish a message using cli

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, command-line-interface

So I'm trying to do the following from the command line:

`> somecommand "Hello world"`

will cause my listening node.js application (RabbitMQ) to receive "hello world" and print it to stdout...

Here's my node.js application (app.js) that's listening for "newTrend" events:

```
var context = require('rabbit.js').createContext();

var sub=null;
context.on('ready', function() {
    sub = context.socket('SUB');
    sub.setEncoding('utf8');

    console.log("Connected to rabbitmq");

    sub.on('newTrend',function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Start using:
`nodejs app.js`

But how to send it "newTrend" events via RabbitMQ using just the command line? I have `rabbitmqadmin` installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there something stopping you from writing a Node.JS program to act as the client?

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var context = require('rabbit.js').createContext();
...
```

Either that or see if rmqcat will do what you need: https://github.com/squaremo/rmqcat

Comment: I don't understand how UDP helps here.